# How to prove statements of the form forall x. phi x in F*?

Tags: fstar

I have just started learning F*, going through the tutorial. One of the exercises there is to prove that the `reverse` function on lists is injective. 
Since this follows from the fact that involutions are injective I would like to express that fact as a lemma in F*. To do that I define

```
let is_involutive f = forall x. (f (f x) == x)
let is_injective f = forall x y. (f x == f y) ==> x == y
```

Is this the right way to define the notion of `f` being involutive or injective in F*?

Then I state the lemma

```
val inv_is_inj: #a:eqtype -> a -> f:(a->a) -> 
    Lemma (requires (is_involutive f)) (ensures(is_injective f))
```

Informally the proof can be written as

```
 { fix (x:a) (y:a)
   assume (f x == f y)
   then have (f (f x) == f (f y))
   with (is_involutive f) have (x == y)
 } hence (forall (x:a) (y:a). f x == f y ==> x == y)
 then have (is_injective f)
```

How do I express such proof in F*? 
In general, what F* language constructs can be used to prove statements of the form `forall (x:a). phi x`, where `phi` is a predicate on a type `a`?